# how to hide the section or content of the tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

There are 4 tabs. i need the content of the 4 tabs should be hidden i.e; the content should visible only when the particular tab is clicked. if 1st tab is clicked, only then the content should be visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```js
      $('.tab_wrpaper').on('click',".tab > li",function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var data_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            $(".tab li").removeClass("nav-tab-active"); // this is for tab 
           list item . to remove active class
            $(this).addClass("nav-tab-active"); // this is for tab list item 
            . to add active class to the clicked list
            $(".tab-content .tab-pane").removeClass("active");  // this is 
            for tab content . to remove active class
            $(".tab-pane[data-id='tab_" + data_id + 
             "']").addClass("active");   // this is for tab content . to add 
            active class          
    
       });
```

```html
<div class="tab_wrapper">
        <div class="tab">
            <li data-id="tab_a">Tab A</li>
            <li data-id="tab_b">Tab B</li>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane" data-id="tab_a">Content A</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" data-id="tab_b">Content B</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```